# Matching tuples of integers within a range of tuples

Tags: swift

The following matching switch statement simetimes seems to work and other times when I change the ranges seems that the choices sometimes make no sense. Seems to be random. Can I expect that the setup as below is correct when trying to match a tuple of integers within a range of integers within other tuples?

```
// tuple case branches


import UIKit

// tuple case branches
let d = (1, 21, 15, 3, 2, 0)

switch d {
case (1...100, 21...100, 14...100, 3...100, 3...100, 0...100):
    println("it's 1st")  // it's 1st
    fallthrough
case (1...100, 21...100, 15...100, 3...100, 2...100, 0...100):
    println("it's 2nd")
    fallthrough
case (1...100, 21...100, 15...100, 3...100, 2...100, 0...100):
    println("it's 3nd")

default:
    println("not 1st or 2nd or 3rd")
```

Comment: Easy to test. Decompose into if statements and check if you get the same result. If you do, likely your data is not what you expect. That being said, I thought the range operator generates iterations rather than defining ranges.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example where the result is not what you expect?

Comment: e.g. `1...100` returns `Range(1,101)` - doubtful that this will match `1`.

Comment: What is missing in the question is a `println("d: \(d)")`.

Comment: You require a 6-tuple to demonstrate this error; or would a 2 or 3 tuple suffice?

Answer (score 1):

The switch will only match the cases when each one of the elements strictly falls into that range. So it's like an AND condition of all of the parts of your tuple.

You are also using fallthrough, which means you're always going to see 'it's 3nd' (did you mean 3rd?) when either the second or third case block is seen.

So in this case, because your penultimate tuple value is 2 it isn't appropriate for the first case statement. 2nd and 3nd are printed because you fallthrough to the next one.